# Not using camel case in RDF URIs?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

If I were to share an ontology with others that used hyphens and periods in URIs, insteadOfCamelCase, e.g. word-word.word-word, is there a compelling reason people would have, to want it changed, other than convention? Also, other than hyphenation in print and confusion with minus in computer code.

This isn't meant to be a poll about camelcase vs something else. I want to know if there is a technical reason to use camelcase in RDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really should be no technical reason to use one versus the other.

You may find some older tools are awkward about `-` in URIs.  However they really shouldn't be since it is a perfectly legal unreserved character in URIs which does not need percent encoding ([RFC 3986 Section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3)).

That's the only technical reason I can think of that people might prefer camel case but if there are tools that have issues then those tools have bugs.

Comment: What @RobV said. Use of camelCase (for property names) and PascalCase (for class names) is convention in the RDF world, but there is no technical requirement to do so.

Comment: @user1905156 I have no problems with `-` in URIs, but it is worth mentioning that many programming languages don't allow `-` in identifiers, creating constants for vocabulary terms can be a pain.  For instance, in Jena it's easy to have a constant `RDFS.subPropertyOf`, but `RDFS.sub-property-of` is not legal.  (That said, I'm also a Common Lisper, where `rdfs::sub-property-of` would be preferable to `rdfs::|subPropertyOf|`.  Indeed, in my [CL-RDFXML library](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~tayloj/CL-RDFXML/) I used, e.g., `+rdf-node-id+` rather than `|+rdf-nodeID+|`.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That being said identifier names and their values are two different things, you can have a `camelCaseIdentifier` whose value `has-hypens-in`

Comment: @RobV Yes, of course;  I didn't mean to imply otherwise.  However, if vocabularies are generated automatically, the automatic conversion is one more task along the way that can introduce problems (not a huge one, but one nonetheless).  In a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047962/rdflib-get-all-uris-under-a-namespace) about the Python RDFlib library, though, we undefined member references for instance of the `Namespace` class get converted into URIs.  E.g., `RDF.fooBar` would become `<rdf-namespace...#fooBar>`.  Such dynamic languages might let programmers blur the line.